# No traffic to Xen vif attached to Openvswitch

Tags: xen, openvswitch

I'm trying to get my guest VMs to use an openvswitch on Ubuntu 12.04 with 3.8.0-26-generic. I've compiled the most recent stable build Xen 4.3.0 but can only get my guest VMs working with a standard Linux bridge. My switch config looks like this after creating a domain via xl create:

```
ea39db23-498c-4427-b57a-f3404cd999b9
  Bridge "xenbr0"
    Port "vif1.0"
        Interface "vif1.0"
    Port "vif1.0-emu"
        Interface "vif1.0-emu"
    Port "eth0"
        Interface "eth0"
    Port "xenbr0"
        Interface "xenbr0"
            type: internal
ovs_version: "1.4.0+build0"
```

I can communicate with the bridge interface from my desktop just fine but the guest attached to vif1.0/vif1.0-emu cannot reach the outside world or the bridge interface on the vswitch. I have ran tshark against the bridge while pinging the guest's IP address and all I see are ARP requests. Its as if the vswitch is not transmitting the traffic to the guest's port. I'm not sure if this is an Openvswitch issue or a Xen issue so feel free to point me in one of those directions if necessary.

Comment: I don't have access to that machine at the moment but to answer your questions directly, the bridge has the IP 10.10.0.5 and the VM has the ip 10.10.0.11. The VM is a NAS4Free box but I could replace this with any OS and get the same results. I have not used DNS in any of my experimentation since I don't have TCP/IP functionality working yet.

Answer (score 0):

You gave so little information. Have you assigned IP to xenbr0? when you use openvswitch or Linux Bridge, you have to move the IP address of eth0 to xenbr0.
Can you make an "ifconfig", I think it's better to let other people look at your configuration. And, have you assigned nameserver address in /etc/resolv.conf on your guest OS?